# Weird collapse behavior in nested bootstrap accordions

Tags: jquery, recursion, bootstrap-accordion

I have built an accordion treeview using bootstrap. I have a few bits of code with which I control the state of the accordions:

```
$('.category-accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(currentTarget) {
    currentTarget.stopPropagation();
    lockUI();
    var categoryId = $(currentTarget.target).attr("id").substr("collapse-".length, $(currentTarget.target).attr("id").length);
    $.ajax({
        url: currentUrl + separator + 'handler=UserCompetencies',
        data: { categoryId: categoryId }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $(currentTarget.target).find('.hideWhenLoaded:last').removeClass("d-flex");
        $(currentTarget.target).find('.hideWhenLoaded:last').addClass("d-none");
        $(currentTarget.target).find('.showWhenLoaded:first').removeClass("d-none");

        $(currentTarget.target).find('.content:last').html(result);
    }).always(function() {
        unlockUI();
    });
});
$('.category-accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(currentTarget) {
    currentTarget.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('.collapse').collapse('hide');

    $(currentTarget.target).find('.hideWhenLoaded:last').removeClass("d-none");
    $(currentTarget.target).find('.hideWhenLoaded:last').addClass("d-flex");

    $(currentTarget.target).find('.showWhenLoaded:first').addClass("d-none");

    $(currentTarget.target).find('.content:last').html("");
});
```

This is the HTML itself, it's a Razor View Component and I call it recursively to build a treeview structure:

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="collapsed disable-when-loading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-@Model.CategoryId" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-@Model.CategoryId">
                        @Model.LocalizedName
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @if (Model.ShowEditAndDeleteActions)
                    {
                        <a asp-page="EditCategory" asp-route-id="@Model.CategoryId"><i class="cursor-pointer text-erni bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a> @:|
                        <a asp-page="DeleteCategory" asp-route-id="@Model.CategoryId"><i class="cursor-pointer text-erni bi bi-trash"></i></a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-@Model.CategoryId" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-@Model.ParentCategoryId" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="category-accordion" id="accordion-@Model.CategoryId">
                    <div class="showWhenLoaded d-none">
                        @foreach (var category in Model.ChildCategories)
                        {
                            @await Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryModelComponent", category)
                        }
                        <div class="content row">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center hideWhenLoaded">
                        <div class="spinner-border text-erni" role="status">
                            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When an accordion is loaded, I load a few things from the server and then render them in a div, which is rendered on each accordion. For this, there are two divs here with a couple of classes, `showWhenLoaded` and `hideWhenLoaded`. I only show `hideWhenLoaded` initially, then when the loading is done, I hide it, show `showWhenLoaded` and append the content to the div with the `content` class.

So far so good. Now when the user collapses an accordion, I also collapse all it's children. I use the function `$(this).find('.collapse').collapse('hide');` to achieve this. This mostly works, but sometimes, when I expand another accordion, the previously open accordion will collapse and the one I expanded will also collapse and I have no idea why this happens. A gif of this behavior can be seen here:

[image]

I think the problem is one of the following functions:

- `$(this).find('.collapse').collapse('hide');`
- `currentTarget.stopPropagation();`

Does anybody have any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid. The problem was indeed this line:

```
$(this).find('.collapse').collapse('hide');
```

The problem was that I used `$(this)` instead of `$(currentTarget.target)`. So simple and yet I wasted hours on this problem lol. Always be mindful of the current scope you're in when writing jQuery.